# How can I match filenames that start with a given string using a RegEx in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript RegEx that matches all `woff` and `woff2` files that start with a particular String, i.e. `MyFont`.

The following examples should match:

```
MyFont-bold.woff
MyFont-light.woff2
```

The following example should not match:

```
GoogleFont-bold.woff
SomeOtherFont-light.woff2
MyFont-something.css
```

Answer (score 0):

`^MyFont.*.woff2?$/` would work.

```js
var regex = /^MyFont.*.woff2?$/

console.log(regex.test('MyFont-bold.woff'))
console.log(regex.test('MyFont-light.woff2'))
console.log(regex.test('GoogleFont-bold.woff'))
console.log(regex.test('SomeOtherFont-light.woff2'))
console.log(regex.test('MyFont-something.css'))
```

Comment: Escape the period before the file extension in your RegEx and you should be good.